# RouteEnhancer with multiple widget links

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have the following route enhancer configuration which is working so far:

```
routeEnhancers:
  Plugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Plugin
    plugin: Plugin
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/test/{var1}', _controller: 'ContactPerson::list', _arguments: { 'var1': '@widget_0/var1' } }
    defaultController: 'Plugin::list'
    defaults:
      var1: 'a'
    requirements:
      var1: '[a-z]'
```

The problem I am facing is that my widget has two arguments (get variables), the second one is optional. So I changed the route enhancer to this:

```
routeEnhancers:
  Plugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Plugin
    plugin: Plugin
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/test/{var1}/{var2}', _controller: 'ContactPerson::list', _arguments: { 'var1': '@widget_0/var1' , 'var2': '@widget_0/var2' } }
    defaultController: 'Plugin::list'
    defaults:
      var1: 'a'
      var2: ''
    requirements:
      var1: '[a-z]'
      var2: '[a-z]'
```

Unfortunately this does not work and my route is not recognized at all anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your var2 default does not match the `requirements`. Thus when resolving an URL there is no match with your routeEnhancer.

It should be

```
defaults:
  var1: 'a'
  var2: ''
requirements:
  var1: '[a-z]'
  var2: '[a-z]*'
```